# how to find straight line which passes throught most number of points?

Tags: straight-line-detection

Suppose I have (x,y,z) scattered random points. I want to find a straight line which passes through most number of data points and if many occurs then what is the maximal length of this straight line. 
What approach shall I follow to solve this problem? [image]

Comment: Did you check out [`Bentley–Ottmann algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley–Ottmann_algorithm)? _In computational geometry, the Bentley–Ottmann algorithm is a sweep line algorithm for listing all crossings in a set of line segments, i.e. it finds the intersection points (or, simply, intersections) of line segments. It extends the Shamos–Hoey algorithm,[1] a similar previous algorithm for testing whether or not a set of line segments has any crossings._

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know. I will check now.